# Alternative regression model algorithms for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I am looking for not so known regression models and if possible a python library that implements it.

In my quiver I have:

- Generalized Linear Models, Linear, Lasso, Ridge...
- Decision Tree based model: CART, Random Forest, Gradient Boosting Decision trees(xgb,lightgbm,catboost)
- Support Vector Machines
- Knn Regressor
- Neural Networks

Are there regression algorithm less known? I am looking for alternatives models to add to my quiver.

Answer (score 1):

```
Multiple regression
multivariate regression
Mixed Models
elastic search
Partial Least Squares regression
Logistic regression
Bayesian regression and many more..
```

When you google you'll find first page suggestions like https://www.listendata.com/2018/03/regression-analysis.html , https://www.techfunnel.com/information-technology/regression-analysis-types/ and https://www.kaggle.com/eraaz1/a-comprehensive-guide-to-advanced-regression

Comment: note that multiple regresion, multivariate regression, elastic search, logistic regression all fall under the category of Generalized Linear Models. So its more of the same

Comment: Really? Ok, didn't know, thanks! Then GLM is quite a lot :)